# Low level event in grpc java

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

The use case is that we have a single stream and channel over which we are sending messages with a very large payload.  At the same time, we also have an app-level ping that is timed out if we don't see a new message in the last 10 seconds. On a slow network, reading the data from the stream takes a lot of time.

The only callback from GRPC we get is onNext when the complete message is read and deserialised. Is there a way to get lower-level events such as stream read is in progress? Or if there is a way to intercept stream reader

```
public interface StreamObserver<V>  {
  /**
   * Receives a value from the stream.
   *
   * <p>Can be called many times but is never called after {@link #onError(Throwable)} or {@link
   * #onCompleted()} are called.
   *
   * <p>Unary calls must invoke onNext at most once.  Clients may invoke onNext at most once for
   * server streaming calls, but may receive many onNext callbacks.  Servers may invoke onNext at
   * most once for client streaming calls, but may receive many onNext callbacks.
   *
   * <p>If an exception is thrown by an implementation the caller is expected to terminate the
   * stream by calling {@link #onError(Throwable)} with the caught exception prior to
   * propagating it.
   *
   * @param value the value passed to the stream
   */
  void onNext(V value);

  /**
   * Receives a terminating error from the stream.
   *
   * <p>May only be called once and if called it must be the last method called. In particular if an
   * exception is thrown by an implementation of {@code onError} no further calls to any method are
   * allowed.
   *
   * <p>{@code t} should be a {@link io.grpc.StatusException} or {@link
   * io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException}, but other {@code Throwable} types are possible. Callers should
   * generally convert from a {@link io.grpc.Status} via {@link io.grpc.Status#asException()} or
   * {@link io.grpc.Status#asRuntimeException()}. Implementations should generally convert to a
   * {@code Status} via {@link io.grpc.Status#fromThrowable(Throwable)}.
   *
   * @param t the error occurred on the stream
   */
  void onError(Throwable t);

  /**
   * Receives a notification of successful stream completion.
   *
   * <p>May only be called once and if called it must be the last method called. In particular if an
   * exception is thrown by an implementation of {@code onCompleted} no further calls to any method
   * are allowed.
   */
  void onCompleted();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ServerInterceptor` or `ServerStreamTracer.Factory` to observe stream event.

Or change the log level for more detail of all event like this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        setLogger("io.grpc");
    }
    
    private static void setLogger(String className) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(handler);
    }
```

If you want print log with logback, just reference this document: [grpc-java-example#log](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample/tree/main/log)